# How to build application in Xcode without launching iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build

I recently purchased an Apple developer's license so I can make apps using Swift

However, whenever I build my app, it takes about five minutes to load, and opens up the iOS simulator which is extremely slow.

How can I build just the app itself?

Thanks.

Comment: I assure you, building all of iOS would take longer than that.

Comment: I guess I didn't state that correctly.  How can I build just the app itself?

Comment: Command-B is the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: (This question was *never* "primarily opinion based". Please take time to read for content, even with hot-word titles. The focus-edits should make it clear.)

Comment: Is this question still relevant today? Cause ARM macs can run iOS apps without Simulator, so why do you need to download the simulator for iOS builds in the newest xcode beta?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the solution is quite simple.
Don't close the iOS simulator, leave it open. 
Just stop the app from running, and it will close the app within the simulator itself.

CommandR to run the app, Command. to close.

Answer (score 0):

You did a "Build & Run" with an iOS Simulator device selected as a run destination.

Select a real iOS device in the run destinations list and B&R to it instead (or just Build rather than B&R).

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>  to build without running simula.